# Angular 8 is not able to import RSA keys using webcryptoAPI

Tags: angular, cryptography, digital-signature, cryptojs, webcrypto-api

I am implementing `Digital Signature` concept in `Angular 8` client and `Python Flask` server. I have created `RSA-2048` keys for client and server from `flask` using `pycryptodome`. I am using `webcrypto API` in `Angular`. I want to import client's keys to sign and verify. However I am unable to import the keys.

RSA Key generation in Flask:

```
import os
import sys
from Crypto.PublicKey import RSA
from Crypto.Util import asn1
from base64 import b64decode

arg = sys.argv[1]    //arg can be 'server' or 'client'
key_path = os.path.join('keysTemp')

#generate private key
key = RSA.generate(2048)
private_key = key.export_key()
file_out = open(os.path.join(key_path, arg + ".private.pem"), "wb")
file_out.write(private_key)

#generate public key
public_key = key.publickey().export_key()
file_out = open(os.path.join(key_path, arg + ".public.pem"), "wb")
file_out.write(public_key)
```

Angular Code snippet (component.ts)

```
export class AppComponent {
    constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

    str2ab(str) {
        const buf = new ArrayBuffer(str.length);
        const bufView = new Uint8Array(buf);
        for (let i = 0, strLen = str.length; i < strLen; i++) {
            bufView[i] = str.charCodeAt(i);
        }
        return buf;
    }
    async importKeys(code: string){
        try {
            let data = await this.http.get('assets/keys/client.private.pem', {responseType: 'text'}).toPromise();
            // fetch the part of the PEM string between header and footer
            const pemHeader = "-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----";
            const pemFooter = "-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----";
            const pemContents = data.substring(pemHeader.length, data.length - pemFooter.length);
            console.log('pemContents: ', pemContents);
            // base64 decode the string to get the binary data
            const binaryDerString = atob(pemContents);
            console.log('binaryDerString: ', binaryDerString);
            // convert from a binary string to an ArrayBuffer
            const binaryDer = this.str2ab(binaryDerString);
            console.log('client private key: ', binaryDer);
            return binaryDer;
        }catch (error) {
          console.error('error ', error);
        }
    }

    async digitalSignature(data){
        let messageDigest = (CryptoJS.MD5(data)).toString();
        console.log('messageDigest: ', messageDigest);

        let clientPrivateKey = await this.importKeys();
        console.log('clientPrivateKey: ', clientPrivateKey);

        try {
            let result = await window.crypto.subtle.importKey('pkcs8', clientPrivateKey, {
                name: "RSA-OAEP",
                hash: {
                    name: "SHA-256"
                }
            }, false, ["decrypt", "sign"]);
            console.log('import result: ', result);
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('error in import: ', error);
        }
    }
}
```

Now when I run the app, client generates arraybuffer, but it gives `DOMexception` as error. It is failing to convert `.pem` file to `CryptoKey` object. Please provide me solution for this. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, after lot of internet search, I found this library: **node-forge** for `angular`. It has wide rage of cryptographic algorithms. For `flask` I used `pycryptodome`. 
See detailed information for [**`node-forge`**](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-forge)

Comment: Are you able to sign using Digital Signature on Client's USB token from client's browser?